# Method is getting called before the constructor

Tags: javascript, websocket

This is my client side websocket code which creates an instance of eventManager and calls the a method.

```
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var eventManager = (function(){
    eventManager.prototype.wsConnection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8081');

    //Constructor to initialize the connection.
    function eventManager(){
        //Open connection on send port.  
        this.wsConnection.on('open', function() {
            console.log('Connection opened');
        }); 
    }

    eventManager.prototype.sendMessage = function(message){
        console.log(message);
        this.wsConnection.send(message); //Send message to websocket server
    }

    return eventManager;
})();

//create instance
var eventManagerObj = new eventManager();
//call method
eventManagerObj.sendMessage("Hi to websockets");
```

When I create the instance, and called the `sendMessage` method,it seems the code inside the constructor is executed after the method call.I want the code inside constructor to execute first to initialize a connection and than send the message.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what your question is, however it might have to do with what happens when entering a function execution context.

The things of relevance here are that first all the code is parsed, then all variables declared with *var* are instantiated (but no assignments are made), then all function declarations are processed, then code execution begins. So in the function expression:

```
var eventManager = (function(){

  eventManager.prototype.wsConnection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8081');

  function eventManager(){
     ...
  }
```

the function declaration means the function is created before any code is executed. When the function is created, by default it has a *prototype* property so on the previous line *eventManager.prototype* exists before the assignment is made.

The logical sequence is as if all variable declarations are moved to the top of the function, immediately followed by all function declarations, but assignments remain where they are. So:

```
// do stuff
function x(){}
var a = 3;
```

is processed as:

```
var a;
function x(){}
// do stuff
a = 3;
```

This is also called "hoisting", but it's not a term I like.

#### Edit

The IIFE is unnecessary in the OP. Normally they are used for closures and to protect methods and variables that should not be exposed publicly, but the OP doesn't use it for that. So it could be written as:

```
function eventManager() {
    //Open connection on send port.  
    this.wsConnection.on('open', function() {
        console.log('Connection opened');
    }); 
}

eventManager.prototype.wsConnection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8081');

eventManager.prototype.sendMessage = function(message){
    console.log(message);
    this.wsConnection.send(message); //Send message to websocket server
}

//create instance
var eventManagerObj = new eventManager();
//call method
eventManagerObj.sendMessage("Hi to websockets");
```

Which also presents the code in a sequence closer to how it is treated logically.

Comment: In my question,could u tell me what happens when I create the instance i.e //create instance
var eventManagerObj = new eventManager(); I assume the constructor is called.

Comment: Yes, the constructor is called. The function named *eventManager* inside the IIFE is returned and assigned to the global variable *eventManager* before that line of code is called.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.wsConnection.on('open', function() {
   console.log('Connection opened');
```

Will log when a connection is opened.

```
eventManager.prototype.sendMessage = function(message){
    console.log(message);
    this.wsConnection.send(message); //
```

Logs the message and then opens a connection that triggers the onOpen of wsConnection so the message logs before "connection opened". The constructor is executed before sendMessage but the open event is triggered in sendMessage.

If you want prove that the constructor code is executed before sendMessage you can add another log:

```
function eventManager(){
    console.log("adding event listener for wsConnection.open");
    //Open connection on send port.  
    this.wsConnection.on('open', function() {
        console.log('Connection opened');
    }); 
}
```